# Making test data for full length of definition uisng Python?

Tags: python

Thanks for your replies to my threads.

I am looking to make a test data to satisfy the full length of field definition using Python Script

For instance, with this data structure:

```
Name varchar (10)
Business Name varchar (15)
Address Varchar (20)
Amount number (10,2)

..........
...........
...........
```

there are many more fields around 70-80 after above sample

I am trying to build a Python script to read the following spec input file that has data like

```
10, x
15, u
20, p
10, 9
```

for 10, x here 10 is the length , 'x' the character to make string of length 10

for 10, 9 here 10 is the length , '9' the digit to make numeric string of length 10

It will make the following output file with delimiter '|'

```
xxxxxxxxxx|uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu|pppppppppppppppppppp|9999999999
```

Some files use ASCII '\031' as delimiter instead of '|'

Am I able to do the above in Python?

How do I do that?

Thanks for your guidance.

## UPDATE

Thanks for sharing python script. I did not improvement.

I have the required spec in a file like

colspec1.data

```
cat colspec1.data
10,x
15,u
20,p
10,9
22,w
18,r
15,9
```

This help me to add many rows as needed.

The changed Python script looks like

```
from csv import reader
final_string = ''
# read csv file as a list of lists
with open('colspec1.data', 'r') as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    # Pass reader object to list() to get a list of lists
    data = list(map(tuple, csv_reader))

    for length, character in data:
        print(int(length))
        final_string += int(length) * str(character) + '|'

print(final_string)
```

The OUTPUT from this script is

```
10
15
20
10
22
18
15
xxxxxxxxxx|uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu|pppppppppppppppppppp|9999999999|wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr|999999999999999|
```

How can I change ASCII '\031' as delimiter instead of '|' in this code ?

Any suggestions for improvement in this script?

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I updated my question with some additions to the script. Pl review and add your comments or alternate way to get this output. Thanks.

Comment: With idea provide to my question. I developed a solution. How do share it here ? Is it OK to post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is coming as a list of tuples (or list of lists) `[(10, 'x'), (15, 'u'), (20, 'p'), (10, 9)]`, you can do this:

```
final_string = ''

for length, character in data:
    final_string += length * str(character) + ' | '

print(final_string)
```

and the output is:

```
xxxxxxxxxx | uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu | pppppppppppppppppppp | 9999999999 |
```

If the input is a dictionary/json, just change the for loop to

```
for length, character in data.values():
```